# Is good practice to throw exceptions in a property with DataMember attribute applied?

Tags: c#, .net, datacontractserializer, datacontract, xml-deserialization

`DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes may be also used in order to serialize an object to file and for deserialization, by using a `DataContractSerializer`. Suppose we have a class with the following private field and public property.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int positiveValue;

    public int PositiveValue
    {
        get { return positiveValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 1)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfBoundException(...);
            positiveValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now suppose we have an XML file containing the state of a previously serialized object, and assume that the user has modified this file, specifying an incorrect value (that is a non positive value) for the `PositiveValue` property. During deserialization an exception would be thrown, since the value in the file is invalid.

Suppose we want to deserialize a list of `MyClass` objects from a file: if some object is not valid, an exception is thrown. Is it possible to make sure that the `DataContractSerializer` ignores invalid objects? Moreover, taking into account the problem just explained, is good practice to throw exceptions in a property with DataMember attribute applied?

Comment: What I do is load bad data then have logic to flag it so the user can fix it.  And logic not to process bad data.   Load files are going to have bad data.  If the user jacked up the XML I don't want then going back to the XML as they may jack it up to not even be valid XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of a list, no you can't make DCS ignore invalid objects. If an exception occurs, the entire deserialize is aborted. If it doesn't throw, it it going to be added to your list.

I would consider checking validity after-and-separate-from deserialization. In some cases, you might be able to just say "ignore invalid items in lists", but frankly in most cases if there is *any* problem you just want to reject the entire thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to validate data when setting properties, but want to bypass these validations during deserialization, you can mark the property's backing field with the `DataMemberAttribute` instead of the property. This will cause the `DataContractSerializer` to set the value directly in the field (not the property) and not throw any validation exceptions.

```
[DataMember]
private int positiveValue;

public int PositiveValue
{
    get { return positiveValue; }
    set
    {
        if (value < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfBoundException(...);
        positiveValue = value;
    }
}
```

Note, that the backing field can be private (otherwise, the property would not make much sense). This works fine with `DataContractSerializer`.

> Moreover, taking into account the problem just explained, is good practice to throw exceptions in a property with DataMember attribute applied?

That depends on whether you want to allow to have objects with invalid data in your application. The advantage of not allowing to set invalid data is that you don't have to check the object each time you use it, but in that case you must check any user input and be prepared for exceptions when loading data. However, I don't think that throwing exceptions in data member properties is wrong. It's just a matter of a design decision.